# Need to create three dependent picklist of role hierarchy using lwc for each level of roles

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning

I am a newbie in LWC so I have to implement the dependent picklist on my custom object and this dependent picklist should be on UserRole along with the upto level 3, like :

3 levels of user role picklist fields to implement: - Level 1: CEO, VP, CTO, ... - Level 2 : (dependent on level 1): - level 3 :( dependent on level 2)

I have created only picklist for entire roles in the org using LWC and I am saving role name in custom field as a URL of role record and I need to do same with both dependent picklist values which means level2(child of level1-parentrole) and level3(child of level2) should also map into two different custom fields as a URL, but I need to make changes according to my requirement. Please help me out.

[image: Org Hierarchy]

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="Display User Role" icon-name="standard:partner_fund_request">
<div class="pickCls slds-m-top_medium">
    <lightning-combobox name="Role" label="Role Name" placeholder="Choose Role" value={value} onchange={handleChange} options={roleOptions}></lightning-combobox>
</div>
<div class="slds-m-top_medium btnCls">        
     <lightning-button class="btnCls1" label="Save" variant="brand" type="submit" onclick={handleSave} alignment-bump="right"></lightning-button>
</div>
</lightning-card>
```

```
public with sharing class UserRoleController {

@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)

public static List<UserRole> getUserRoles(){

return [SELECT Id, Name FROM UserRole];

 }

}
```

```
import { LightningElement , wire, track,api} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import getUserRoles from '@salesforce/apex/UserRoleController.getUserRoles';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Invoice__c.Id'; 
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import USER_ROLES_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Invoice__c.Role_link__c';
let i=0;
export default class DisplayUserRole extends LightningElement {
 @api recordId;
 @track items = []; //this will hold key, value pair
 @track value = ''; //initialize combo box value
 @track chosenValue = '';
 @wire(getUserRoles)
 wiredUserRoles({ error, data }) {
 if (data) {
     for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
     this.items = [...this.items ,{value: data[i].Id , label: data[i].Name} ];
 }
 this.error = undefined;
 } else if (error) {
     this.error = error;
 }
 }
 get roleOptions() {
     return this.items;
 }
 handleChange(event) {
     const selectedOption = event.detail.value;
     if(selectedOption != undefined && selectedOption != ""){
         this.chosenValue = selectedOption;
     }   
 }
 get selectedValue(){
 return this.chosenValue;
 }
 handleSave() {
     if (!this.chosenValue) {
         const event = new ShowToastEvent({
             title: 'Error',
             message: 'Please select a value from the picklist.',
             variant: 'error',
         });
         this.dispatchEvent(event);
       }
 const fields = {};
fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordId; 
var recordUrl = window.location.origin;
const recordUrl1= recordUrl+'/lightning/setup/Roles/page?address=%2F'+this.chosenValue;
fields[USER_ROLES_FIELD.fieldApiName] = recordUrl1;
let recordInput = {fields};
updateRecord(recordInput)
.then(() => {
 if (this.chosenValue != ""){
     this.showToast('Success',' Record is updated successfully.', 'success');
     this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
 }
})
.catch((error) => {
 this.showToast('Error', 'Error updating record.', 'error');
 //console.log('Error updating', error);
}); 
}
showToast(title, message, variant){
const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
 title: title,
 message: message,
 variant: variant,
 duration: 2000
});
this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
}
updateRecordView() {
setTimeout(() => {
eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
}, 1000);
}
}
```